# Why does it say "dir"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Why does it say

> Du willst ***dir*** das Zimmer anschauen.

Why *"dir"*?

Comment: related: [Usage concerning “mir/mich”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39629/usage-concerning-mir-mich)

Comment: related: [niemandem Rechenschaft abzulegen haben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41117/niemandem-rechenschaft-abzulegen-haben)

Comment: related: [Why the dative pronoun in “Ich wasche mir die Hände”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38925/why-the-dative-pronoun-in-ich-wasche-mir-die-hände)

Comment: related: [“Ja, das dachte ich mir.” – Why “mir”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33651/ja-das-dachte-ich-mir-why-mir)

Comment: related: [Usage of “dem Jäger” in “Ein Schwarm Tauben war dem Jäger ins Netz gegangen”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40210/usage-of-dem-jäger-in-ein-schwarm-tauben-war-dem-jäger-ins-netz-gegangen)

Comment: I marked this as duplicate, although it is no direct duplicate. Nevertheless you will find your answer by reading the questions provided by @HubertSchölnast

Comment: What is your linguistic background? What is your native language, and what other language do you have some command of?

Comment: Not all questions above will answer your concern. You may want to learn about [reflexive use of verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=reflexive%20verbs) - if in doubt, or if you have further questions on the reflexive usage of *anschauen* - please do not hesitate to [edit] this into your question.